# Fail to pass/use string argument for img to html file in Django app?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am very new to Django and was trying to pass one argument as a string to my html file so that I can call to use my image.

I have the below code to call static image:

```
{% load static %}
<img src= "{{ user_age_pic_name }}" width=950 height=450px padding = 40px alt="" >
```

However, this is not working (I also tried deleting the double quote).

I know the image is correct because when I call

```
<img src= "{% static 'research/used_viz/comparative/age/12-15.jpg' %}" width=950 height=450px padding = 40px alt="" >
```

The img works perfectly.

I also try to just print out the text and it seems to work fine. I think it should be cause by limited understanding of HTML arguments. Could someone guide me through this? Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add .url

```
<img src= "{{ user_age_pic_name.url }}" width=950 height=450px padding = 40px alt="" >
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the response! I just tried and it did not work. The string that I am strong for user_age_pic_name is in fact "{% static 'research/used_viz/comparative/age/12-15.jpg' %}"  this whole thing. So I am not sure that will help.